# Rendering a Rails view from within a Sidekiq Worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, background-process, sidekiq

I have a Sidekiq worker that does some background processing and then finally POSTs a success message to a 3rd party API.  This message I post is essentially a "thank you" message and can contain HTML.

In the message I'd like to link back to my site in a properly formatted way. This naturally sounds like a view to me.  I'd love to simply use a view template, render it to HTML and finally post it off to the API.

For the life of me, i cannot figure how to render a view from within my Sidekiq worker.

I have considered setting up a dummy controller/view combo and instantiating it from inside the worker but it seems wrong.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside your worker you can use ActionView::Base directly to render a view. For example, to render a `users/events` partial:

```
view = html = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.root.join('app/views'))
view.class.include ApplicationHelper
view.render(
  partial: 'users/event', 
  object: user.events.last
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is almost perfect... I'm unable to use view helpers like `url_for` etc in my template. Do you know if it's possible to have this feature?

Comment: For anyone reading this, if you want to access more than your own view helpers you may have to include `view.class.include  Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ERB` for rendering template in your job.

```
require 'erb'

@text = "my answer" # variables, accessible in template.
template = "This is <%= @text %>."

# you can also render file like ERB.new(File.read(<file name here>))
renderer = ERB.new(template)
puts output = renderer.result()
```

More about [**ERB**](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/)