# How to use a helper in a view that has been called by a Rails sidekiq worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am backgrounding an automated reporting process through the use of a Sidekiq worker; however, the views call some methods that are defined within helpers, but cannot access them because the helpers are not available when called via a Sidekiq worker.

How can I accomplish this? Here's an example of what I have going on:

```
# app/helpers/report_helper.rb

def random_uuid_method
  return SecureRandom.hex(10)
end
```

```
# app/workers/sidekiq/report_generator_worker.rb

class ReportGeneratorWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options queue: Rails.env.to_sym
    
    def perform
        ac_base = ActionController::Base.new()
        body_html = ac_base.render_to_string template: 'common/report_templates/generate_pdf.html.erb', layout: false
    end
end
```

```
# app/views/common/report_templates/generate_pdf.html.erb

Here's your UUID: <%= random_uuid_method %>
```

This is just an example. I understand that `SecureRandom.hex(10)` in a normal case scenario could just be directly called from within the view, but I am trying to access the methods defined within a worker. When I do this, I get an error in the console telling me that `random_uuid_method` is an undefined method.

Comment: you have a typo in definition arndom_uuid_method

Comment: Fixed, thanks. It was just an example so sorry about that. Still have the same problem

Comment: not sure that it is good Idea to use such method, it looks like delegate, what it you replace  <%= random_uuid_method %> with  <%= SecureRandom.hex(10) %>
if it will help I think the better way will use it, instead make life harder)

Comment: Well, again, the bottom of the post says that this is just an example. I am not using SecureRandom.hex(10) in my code, but something more sensitive (cannot share). The same concept applies though. I am trying to access a method that is stored within a helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Application Controller directly instead. Like this:

```
app_controller = ApplicationController.new
body_html = app_controller.render_to_string template: 'common/report_templates/generate_pdf.html.erb', layout: false
```

The difference is that `ActionController::Base` does not include helpers, `ApplicationController` on the other hand does include them

Comment: Confused. The first sentence contradicts the example at the end. Did you mean instead of ActionController?

Comment: Change `ac_base = ActionController::Base.new()` for `ac_base = ApplicationController.new`, the reason is that with `ApplicationController` you get helpers, with `ActionController::Base` you don't.

Answer (score 0):

try to include them ApplicationHelper, or ReportHelper

```
ac_base.class.include ApplicationHelper
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but unfortunately the view file still cannot access the method that is located within the ReportHelper :(

Comment: sorry, I tried, but no more ideas, take a look at the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099926/rendering-a-rails-view-from-within-a-sidekiq-worker meabe it will help